# How to write a greek letter in a item list

Tags: errors, greek

I am trying to add the character "alpha" in the title of a list like this:

```
  \item \alpha value
```

so that I see the bullet, a alpha letter and the word "value", all in the same row.

Even though I see the result I want in the preview, I have this errors:

```
Missing $ inserted
Missing } inserted
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, any tips?

Comment: You can use `\item[\textbullet $\alpha$ value]` maybe. Note that `\alpha` needs to be in mathmode, within `$$`.

Comment: "\item $\alpha$ value" worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error

```
Missing $ inserted
Missing } inserted
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup
```

is due to the fact that `\alpha` needs to be in mathmode; hence, within `$<math content>$`. Therefore, using

```
\item $\alpha$ value
```

should fix the issue.

The following is just a suggestion to look into. It is not fully optimized.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength{\alphaitemize}
\setlength{\alphaitemize}{\widthof{\textbullet~$\alpha$ value}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet~$\alpha$ value:,itemindent=\alphaitemize]
        \item 23
        \item 24
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $\alpha$ value: 23
        \item $\alpha$ value: 23
    \end{itemize}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Note that changed the labeling of the itemization to be more effective.